# RelayCommand not executing in my code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to build a fairly simple WPF application to test out MVVM and use it to switch views(with no codebehind). The way it's supposed to work, on startup I want it to load the Def.xaml and on clicking the button, it's supposed to switch the view. The problem I'm having is the RelayCommand doesn't seem to be firing on the button click event and the view isn't changing. Also, I'm not sure if I'm setting the initial view in the correct manner. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated. My code is as follows:

**AppViewModel.cs - This is the ViewModel for the MainWindow.xaml**

```
namespace Test
{
    class AppViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private ICommand ActivateView { get; set; }
        private ICommand DeactivateView { get; set; }

        public AppViewModel()
        {
            ActiveView = new DefViewModel();
            ActivateView = new RelayCommand(UnsetDef);
            DeactivateView = new RelayCommand(SetDef);
        }

        private void UnsetDef(object obj)
        {
            ActiveView = new AltViewModel();
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
        }

        private void SetDef(object obj)
        {
            ActiveView = new DefViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DefViewModel}">
            <local:def/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AltViewModel}">
            <local:Alt/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:AppViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=ActiveView}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Def.xaml - This is my default view**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.def"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Padding="15,15,15,15" Text="Default View Active"/>
            <Button Padding="1,1,1,1" Content="Activate Alt View" Command="{Binding Path=ActivateView}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Alt.xaml - This is my alternative view**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Alt"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Padding="15,15,15,15" Text="Alt View Active"/>
            <Button Padding="1,1,1,1" Content="Deactivate Alt View" Command="{Binding Path=DeactivateView}"/>
        </StackPanel>        
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ObservableObject.cs - This is an abstract class I made to implement INotifyPropertyChanged**

```
namespace Test
{
    public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        private object activeView;
        public object ActiveView
        {
            get { return activeView; }
            set { activeView = value; OnPropertyChanged("ActiveView"); }
        }
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
namespace Test
{
    class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("execute"); _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        //private Action<object> _action;

        //public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
        //{
        //    _action = action;
        //}

        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
            //if(parameter != null)
            //{
            //    _action(parameter);
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    _action("Nyet!");
            //}
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

UPDATE: bwing's suggestion to change binding to reference the parent datacontext worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Commands to which you are binding need to be public.

```
public ICommand ActivateView { get; }
public ICommand DeactivateView { get; }
```

Also, if you're not going to change the command at run-time you can make them readonly.

UPDATE:
The other problem is that your button is binding to the wrong DataContext. The Template applied to the ContentControl gets the DefViewModel as its context.

To get it to work like this move the ActivateView command to the DefViewModel.
or a little uglier solution is to change your binding to reference the parent datacontext.

```
<Button Padding="1,1,1,1" Content="Activate Alt View" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ActivateView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but it still won't get it to work. Thanks for the tip about making the command read-only though!

Comment: For debugging Binding problems I'd recommend downloading Snoop. https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ It can help you find binding errors. Also you can look at the Output window of Visual Studio to see Binding failures as well.

Comment: It worked! Specifically, changing the binding to reference the parent Data Context did the trick.Thank you very much!!!

I will try moving the ActivateView command to the DefViewModel to see if that works. But it is my understanding that it would violate the MVVM architecture. Is that correct? 

Also, thanks for recommending snoop. I will find great use for it as I build more complex stuff

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting a command in another view model. However, in your case the AppViewModel contains the property that needs to be updated so it makes sense to leave it where it is.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you!